# Problem about orbit size in orbifold

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, orbifolds

Suppose S is a genus g surface with a hyperbolic manifold structure.

Assume a finite group H acting on S.Does the orbit size of each point in orbifold S/H divides |H|?

Also is it always true that size of each orbit in S/H is precisely |H|?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- Given two points $x, y$ in the same orbit, can you describe some relation between the set of elements of $H$ mapping $x$ to $x$ and the elements mapping $x$ to $y$?
- Does $H$ necessarily act freely?

Comment: All I can think of is if E denotes the elements mapping x to y then cardinality of E is same as no of cosets of stabilizer of x in H.Can you please elaborate?

Comment: $E$ is some coset of the stabilizer of $x$.

Comment: Ok,but how that concludes my problem?

Comment: Since all cosets have the same size, the orbit size is equal to the group size divided by the stabilizer size.